# AJAX submit function with alert does not work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

im trying to get an ajax submit function to work. i cant find what the issue is here. the button for submit is inside a table inside a form

i tried using alert to see if its working but it still not.

the method-

```
$("#submit").submit(function(){//comparing the total quoted hours with duration of time selected 

         alert("DEMO TEST");
         // code for the comparing values goes here but that's another 
         //story


});
```

the submit button-

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id="submit" onclick="index.php">
```

obviously the alert should pop an alert with `DEMO TEST`. 
i dont know where im going wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just because of you are calling submit event. When you call submit event your form will submit. you need to take **id** and **class** of form like.

```
<form action="" id="formsubmit">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"> //Remove name="submit" onclick="index.php"
</form> 

$("#formsubmit").submit(function(){
         alert("DEMO TEST");
});
```

Comment: Glad to helped.

Answer (score 1):

You have to point the .submit to your form, not your button.
More info on how submit works on jQuery https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Answer (score 0):

jQuery on click event is getting triggered first as onclick="index.php" so remove it and submit the form then it will work.or if you want that event to be trigerred you should return true. or you can submit form using jQuery using .submit() and after submitting the form you can use location.href